# Inconsistent results from BigQuery: same query, different number of rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed today that one my query was having inconsistent results: every time I run it I have a different number of rows returned (cache deactivated).
Basically the query looks like this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM mydataset.table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN EACH mydataset.table2 AS t2
  ON t1.deviceId=t2.deviceId
LEFT JOIN EACH mydataset.table3 AS t3
  ON t2.email=t3.email
WHERE  t3.email IS NOT NULL
AND (t3.date IS NULL OR DATE_ADD(t3.date, 5000, 'MINUTE')<TIMESTAMP('2016-07-27 15:20:11') )
```

The tables are not updated between each query. So I'm wondering if you also have noticed that kind of behaviour.

I usually make queries that return a lot of rows (>1000) so a few missing rows here and there is hardly noticeable. But this query return a few row, and it varies everytime between 10 and 20 rows :-/

If a Google engineer is reading this, here are two Job ID of the same query with different results:
picta-int:bquijob_400dd739_1562d7e2410
picta-int:bquijob_304f4208_1562d7df8a2

Comment: can you provide an example or two of your `t3.date` and what datatype of this field

Comment: in my query, t3.date is TIMESTAMP and is NULL

Comment: try to run without EACH - will you see same behavior? I would suspect some EACH related bug - sorry for wild speculation

Comment: unfortunately I have the same issue without the EACH

Comment: honestly - happy to hear this in a sense that it is not Bug with EACH :o)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the query that you provide is completely deterministic and so should give the same result every time you execute it. But you say it's "basically" the same as your real query, so this may be due to something you changed.

There's a couple of things you can do to try to find the cause:

- replace `select *` by an explicit selection of fields from your tables (a combination of fields that uniquely determine each row)
- order the table by these fields, so that the order becomes the same each time you execute the query
- simplify your query. In the above query, you can remove the first condition and turn the two left outer joins into inner joins and get the same result. After that, you could start removing tables and conditions one by one.

After each step, check if you still get different result sets. Then when you have found the critical step, try to understand why it causes your problem. (Or ask here.)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that sampling is disabled. It could produce inconsistent results for your queries.

In my case it was an issue.

[image]